# Does Ron and Harry's flight in the flying car in CoS count as under age wizardry?

Tags: harry-potter

And if it does, shouldn't they have had a hearing at the Ministry of Magic like when Harry conjured his Patronus in front of Dudley on OoP?

Comment: Technically, the car was already enchanted, so the only magic they performed was unlocking it.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose technically it did *not* constitute underage wizardry because neither Harry nor Ron received a disciplinary letter from Mafalda Hopkirk, of the Improper Use of Magic Office at the Ministry of Magic. Also, apparently it was an emergency:

> ‘We’re stuck, right? And we’ve got to get to school, haven’t we? And even underage wizards are allowed to use magic if it’s a real emergency, section nineteen or something of the Restriction of Thingy ...’
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 56 - Bloomsbury - chapter 5, *The Whomping Willow*</sub>

Comment: Good answer. Clearly it wasn't a violation.  It's also consistent with canon in the example of Sirius' motorbike.   When they needed to get Harry out in THBP, they used "modes of transportation that the trace couldn't detect, like brooms, and thestrals" (and Sirius' bike) If the trace didn't count a motorcycle with a flying charm, the same rule would probably apply to a car with a flying charm. Using a bewitched object doesn't appear to be the same as performing underage magic. Car, broom, motorbike, no difference.

Comment: @DavidStratton - Thanks :) You wrote exactly what I thought about using bewitched items as opposed to casting magic. Although why Harry and Ron didn't get a Hopkirk letter in what was not *really* an emergency, yet Harry was expelled for the Dementor attack in *OotP*, which was essentially a life-threatening emergency, is beyond me. Ron also tried to cast magic with his wand as the car was falling out of the Whomping Willow, but perhaps being caught in the Whomping Willow is considered an emergency as well. :)

Comment: Harry's expulsion after the Dementor attack was purely politics; the Ministry was doing everything they could to discredit him, making him out to be delusional and dangerous makes that much, much easier. Considering that Dudley was his cousin - and therefore already knew he was a wizard and about the wizarding world - it made absolutely no sense to me for Harry to be charged with breaking the Statute of Secrecy.

Comment: As for the Whomping Willow incident: That was on school grounds after the school year had officially started so surely wouldn't count as underage magic anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The Ministry expects Hogwarts to take disciplinary action against Harry and Ron for misuse of magic instead of the Ministry taking action, and their laws probably support that.

Recall Harry's attempted defense from CS chapter 5:

> ‘And speaking of Gryffindor –’ Professor McGonagall said sharply, but Harry cut in: ‘Professor, when we took the car, term hadn't started, so – so Gryffindor shouldn't really have points taken from it, should it?’ he finished, watching her anxiously.

This was a desperate attempt from Harry with nothing to back it up, and I don't think Professor McGonagall buys it at all.  I'm sure both Professor McGonagall and the Ministry considers Hogwarts being responsible for students as soon as their parents drop them to the Hogwarts Express.  Professor Snape was also clear in considering this a Hogwarts matter.

While McGonagall doesn't take any points from Gryffindor, this is definitely not because she's not allowed to take points for an offense committed before Dumbledore officially opens the term.  I'll try to explain the reasons why she doesn't take points in the rest of this post.

---

Firstly, Professor McGonagall clearly wanted to try to keep the story secret, knowing how other students would react.

Secondly, Professor McGonagall was very effective in disciplining young students.  By not giving Harry and Ron a severe punishment immediately, she might make them think they have a debt to her and might convince them to behave better or else they will get expelled at the next offense.  (Professor McGonagall must have learned pedagogy from Professor Dumbledore.)

Thirdly, Professor McGonagall knows that, with the term just starting, Gryffindor likely doesn't have any points yet, and  the points are capped from below by zero.  OOTP chapter 38 implies this strongly, when Professor Snape wants to punish Harry:

> ‘Put that wand away at once,’ he said curtly. ‘Ten points from Gryff—’
>
> Snape looked towards the giant hour-glasses on the walls and gave a sneering smile.
>
> ‘Ah. I see there are no longer any points left in the Gryffindor hour-glass to take away.  In that case, Potter, we simply have to –’